# Нужно создать составной первичный ключ для таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Есть следующие таблицы:

```
TOVAR
KTOV|NTOV   |SORT
1   | Вода   |без газа
2   | Сок    |яблочный
3   | Яблоки |голден
```

KTOV- код товара(первичный ключ) ,NTOV - наименование,SORT - сорт товара

```
DOCUMENT1
DDM        | NDM| PR
01/03/2017 | 11 | 1
01/03/2017 | 22 | 1
01/03/2017 | 33 | 2
```

DDM - дата документа,NDM - номер документа( первичный ключ),PR - приход / расход (1- приход,2 - расход)

```
DOCUMENT2
KTOV | KOL | CENA  | SORT     | NDM
1    | 2   | 10.20 | без газа | 11 |
2    | 3   | 20.50 | яблочный | 22 | 
3    | 1   | 14.99 | голден   | 33 |
```

где KOL - количество

Какой составной первичный ключ можно задать последней таблице(DOCUMENT2),не добавляя туда больше никаких полей? (Извиняюсь за кривую передачу таблиц, пыталась как можно точнее описать представление)

Comment: В большинстве организаций документы нумеруются в пределах года, вы уверены, что номер документа можно делать первичным ключом

Comment: Так изначально было указано в задании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы в каждой таблице все-таки держал уникальный айдишник, не люблю составные ключи.

В данном же случае напрашивается составной ключ из полей NDM и KTOV. Пример скрипта:

```
CREATE TABLE [DOCUMENT2](
KTOV int not null,
KOL int not null,
CENA decimal(18,3) not null,
SORT vnarchar(50) not null, -- вот это поле я бы исключил. денормализация. его всегда можно получить из таблицы TOVAR
NDM int not null,
CONSTRAINT [DOCUMENT2_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KTOV ASC, NDM ASC))
```

UPD: второе поле в ключе должно быть NDM, как ссылка на таблицу DOCUMENT1. ASC - порядок сортировки индекса, во-возростанию. Можно указать по-убыванию одно или оба поля - DESC.

Comment: Что значит ASC и почему два одинаковых поля сюда записывается? 
(KTOV ASC, KTOV ASC)

Comment: ALTER TABLE DOCUMENT2
ADD CONSTRAINT DOCUMENT2_PK PRIMARY KEY (KTOV,KOL)

Я по примеру вот так пыталась создать. 
Так будет неправильно?

Comment: С кластеризацией разобралась и с asc тоже. Но почему здесь нужно использовать именно кластеризированный индекс?

Comment: @SoftySh особой разницы нет, писать clustered или не писать, primary key автоматически будет создан кластаризованным если в таблице до этого не было кластаризованных индексов

Comment: Спасибо большое.Разобралась.